103M 125L ceramic capacitors
I have a SWR LA15 bass amp. On the power entry module. There's two 103M 125L ceramic capacitors connected to the power entry module. If you look at the picture. You can tell that they have better days.

(Click the image above for a larger image.)
All the capacitors I have are the electrolytic capacitors. May I use them in place of the ceramic capacitors? As long as the voltage and uF are the same.

If they're on the power entry module, are you sure they're capacitors and not varistors?

They are ceramic capacitors the two shown are the original capacitors. With one of my multimeters. I can't get any type of reading. I do believe that I have two more identical to what is showing. There was nothing wrong with it. Until someone didn't pull the IEC cord out. Before they laid it down on it's back. When they loaded it in the bed of my truck.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm just wanted to know if I could use electrolytic capacitors. What type of capacitors should I use? I believe that I have found my answers

It looks like the AC mains input connector where these devices are connected. They are probably 10 nF ±20% capacitors since they are marked with 103M (103 is the value, M denotes the tolerance). These are safety certified capacitors as denoted by all the worldly safety agency logos on the capacitors.
You can NOT use electrolytic capacitors at this point since this is mains AC voltage and electrolytics aren't safety certified. Be safe and use the proper devices if they need replacing.

Thank you! For letting me know if I can use electrolytic capacitors. Plus for explaining to me about the different logos. I know I have two 103m ceramic capacitors floating around my place somewhere. I am a lot more careful now. Than I was when I started replacing the power entry module. Especially about the capacitors. I didn't know that they stored electricity. I'm extremely thankful that my SWR LA15 has not been plugged in and playing since December of 2018. If whoever loaded it in the bed of my truck. Would have pulled the IEC cord out. I wouldn't be here asking about the capacitors.

@AllenStroker They must be Y-rated.

Those are mains filter caps.
They must have a rated safety class, at least equal or better than what reads on them.
The photo is so blurry you can't see the X or Y class ratings and voltages printed in the middle of the capacitor.
But you don't say which capacitors you have, because you cannot replace these with any capacitor for continued safety against electrical shocks and fire hazards.
Do not replace these unless you understand what capacitors are safe and legal according to your local laws and regulations about electrical safety. If you use a capacitor not intended for that usage, it will not have the proper approval markings, and if this device causes death by electrocution or burns down a building, it might get you in trouble for servicing it with unsafe components.
In other words, have someone professional to service the device for you that can be held responsible for servicing it properly.
The capacitors are likely fine. Even if they are not, the safety caps should blow open. You can remove the caps and the device should still work, these capacitors are likely not needed for the functioning of the device, being installed at the mains inlet, it looks like an afterthought to pass local electrical regulation compliance tests for EMI and EMC with a cheap power supply.
